# How do I convert an array of tuple strings to an array of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, shapely

My situation is that I'm trying to convert an array of tuples in a string format into an array of tuples.

i.e. I want to go from:

```
['(-109.080842,45.002073)','(-105.91517,45.002073)','(-109.080842,45.002073)']
```

to

```
[(-109.080842,45.002073),(-105.91517,45.002073),(-109.080842,45.002073)]
```

The purpose of this is to be able to create a shapely Polygon.  It throws an error when the tuples are a string.  What is the best way to go from strings to actual tuple objects?

Comment: You can parse tuples of builtin Python objects with `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: But, before you run off and do that—why do you have reprs of tuples as strings in the first place? If you're storing data by writing it to a file that way, there are much better ways to do it.

Comment: @abarnert Poor coding from someone else where they manipulated the string to get it in an odd format.  Turns out I can straight up just do the ast.literal_eval on the string returned from the postgres polygon type and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>They're literals, so</strike> you can safely evaluate them:

```
>>> import ast
>>> L = ['(-109.080842,45.002073)','(-105.91517,45.002073)','(-109.080842,45.002073)']
>>> [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in L]
[(-109.080842, 45.002073), (-105.91517, 45.002073), (-109.080842, 45.002073)]
```

Comment: [They're actually not literals.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#literals) But `literal_eval` does work on them anyway.

Comment: Hmm odd, when I printed my array of tuple strings after doing a ast.literal_eval it showed them as strings still, but it did work when passing it into the shapely Polygon.  Thanks!

Comment: @abarnert  Huh.  TIL.

Answer (score 0):

This is the functional way with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

lst = ['(-109.080842,45.002073)','(-105.91517,45.002073)','(-109.080842,45.002073)']

res = list(map(literal_eval, lst))

# [(-109.080842, 45.002073), (-105.91517, 45.002073), (-109.080842, 45.002073)]
```